# Grade 9/10 honours math question on averages

Tags: average

How do I find the greatest integer that could appear on a token when all the info I have is  55=(n-68/t-1) or 56=(n/t) and n=the numbers on all the tokens in the bag added up and t=the number of tokens in the bag.  The equations are about average numbers of tokens in the bag (the averages are, in the two equations, 55, and 56)

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed to be on the tokens?

Comment: Is it $55=(n-\frac {68}t-1)$, which is what you wrote but I suspect is not what you intended or $\frac {n-68}{t-1}$ or $n-\frac {68}{t-1}$ or what?  Please be careful with partentheses or, better, see the FAQ for MathJax.